# Get the characters after the last index of a substring from a string

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a string which is an output of another command. I only need the end of this string to display. The separator string is "`.`" (dot and space), and I need the string after the last index of "`.`".

How can I do this in Bash?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try this:

```
your cmd...|sed 's/.*\. //'
```

this works no matter how many "dot" or "dot and space" do you have in your input. it takes the string after the **last** "dot and space"

Comment: @sputnick no, the two are different. mine works for OP, yours not. :)

Answer (score 53):

If the string is in a variable:

```
$ foo="header. stuff. more stuff"
$ echo "${foo##*. }"
more stuff
```

If there are multiple instances of ". " (as in my example) and you want everything after the *first* occurrence, instead of the last, just use one `#`:

```
$ echo "${foo#*. }"
stuff. more stuff
```

Comment: Perfect, it wud've been great if you explained the difference between `#` and `##` in more details.

Comment: If anyone is wondering, the inverse, getting everything *before* the first occurrence is done with a `%` instead of a `#`. For example: `echo "${foo%%*. }"`

Answer (score 18):

Awk is elegant weapon...for a more civilized age:

```
[cpetro01@h ~]$ echo "this. is. my. string. of. some. arbitrary. length" | awk -F'. ' ' { print $NF } '
length
[cpetro01@h ~]$ echo "this. is. my. string. of. some" | awk -F'. ' ' { print $NF } '   
some
```

In this case NF is the awk variable for "Number of fields" and this construct says "print the entry in highest number of fields found" so if the size of your input changes from one line to the next you're still going to get the last one.

You can also do math:

```
[cpetro01@h~]$ echo "this. is. my. string. of. some. arbitrary. length" | awk -F'. ' ' { print $(NF-2) } '
some
[cpetro01@h~]$ echo "this. is. my. string. of. some. arbitrary. length" | awk -F'. ' ' { print $(NF-3) } '
of
[cpetro01@h~]$
```

(Yes, this is 3 years late for the OP, but one of my cow-orkers pointed me to this page today for something we were working on, so I thought I'd drop this here in case others are looking too.)

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
echo "This is a sentence. This is another sentence" | rev | cut -d "." -f1 | rev
```

The `rev` reverses the output. The `-d` specifies the delimiter, breaking everything up into fields. The   `-f` specifies the fields you want to use. We can select f1, because we reversed the data. We don't need to know how many fields there are in total. We just need to know the first. At the end, we reverse it again, to put it back in the right order.

Comment: -1 the delimiter is dot-space, not dot. This answer will give you a leading space.

Comment: You should read again the question (I do the same error in first instance)

Comment: Clever! This makes a lot more sense to me than the other answers. More readable - IMHO. Thanks.